# Serialize and deserialize in Java with arrays, or other ways to save an array for a future run

Tags: java, file

I'm working with Java to manage a history of keychain counts and names, storing them as objects in a temporary file for persistence between sessions. My objective is to serialize a String array containing a name and keychain count and append this data to a temp file. Here is my current approach:

```html
public static void order_history() {
    String[][] newArray = {{name, String.valueOf(keychain_count)}};
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("t.tmp");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(newArray);
        oos.close();
    } catch (IOException i) {
        i.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I need to ensure that each time a new array is created, it's appended to the 't.tmp' file rather than overwriting the previous data. Also, I want to be able to read back all the serialized objects in the file to process them later.

Could someone guide me on how to modify this code to append the new array to the file correctly and read the accumulated data afterwards?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [storing an array in a file in java](/q/1503424/90527), [how to write an array to a file Java](/q/13707223/90527)

Answer (score 1):

To **load** array from file use these input streams:

```java
String[][] loaded = null;
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("t.tmp");
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
    loaded = (String[][]) ois.readObject();
    ois.close();
} catch (IOException i) {
    i.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Don't forget to check that the array is **loaded successfully**:

```java
if (loaded == null) {
    // save file is corrupted, you need to create a new data from scratch
}
```

Comment: Is the data from the file saved in the variable loaded? When I print out loaded, I get this value: "[[Ljava.lang.String;@5a2e4553"

Comment: @VSPuzzler, your code is using a two-dimensional array of strings to store your data. Therefore to get, for example, "name" you need to write: `loaded[0][0]` (based on your code in question). If you want to print the whole array, use this: `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(loaded));`. By the way, ObjectStreams support any objects (except primitive types like int, char, ...), so you can encode your data in your custom class variable. If my answer was helpful and solves your question, then accept it, thanks :)